# show all images in my products page from a selected category when a category link is selected- php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show all images in my products page from a selected category when a category link is selected. My database table has 'id', 'name', 'size', 'category_id', 'image_path'. My uploading of images and saving to database and to a selected category all work correctly, I have a page where I can delete from database and that works correctly. My `products.php` file is below and I need assistance if some one can help.

```
<?php 
    require_once ("Includes/session.php");
    require_once ("Includes/simplecms_config.php"); 
    require_once  ("Includes/connectDB.php");
    include("Includes/header.php");    
    confirm_is_admin();     
?>
<section>
<?php
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$category_id = $_GET['category_id'];

$query = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id =         '".$category_id."'");

        echo '<div id="main_products">';

        echo '<h1 style="margin-left: 85px;">Golf '.$category_id.'</h1><br /><br />';

$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($row_count == 0) {
        echo '<p style="color:red">There are no images uploaded for this category</p>';
    } elseif ($query) {

         echo '<table style="text-align:center;">';


        while($prod = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {            
            echo '<tr><td>'; 

            $file = $prod['/Golfsite/uploads/'];
            $name = $prod['name'];
            $id = $prod['id'];  
            $category_id = $prod['category_id']; 
            $image_path = $prod['image_path'];                     

echo '<img src="'.$file.'" height="150" width="175" margin="10" float="center" border="0" title="'.$name.'" />';

            echo '</td></tr>';
         }
         echo '</table>'; 
     } 
     else
        {
            die('There was a problem with the query: ' .$query->error);             
        }  
?>

</div>
</section>
<br />
<?php 
include ("Includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first check ur **$_GET['category_id']** value , what is coming in this variable and if this is picking right category value then go and **echo ur sql query and run this query into ur mysql database** and see the result .if the result set is coming properly then the query is right otherwise there is problem in between these 2 cases.